# python read yaml file with variable substitution

Tags: python, yaml

I use the yaml library to read yaml files, and it works great. My only issue is with the variable substitution.

For instance, here is a simple example of yaml file I want to read:

```
queues:
    mail-queue-name: mail-app-test
    mail-dlq-name: ${queues.mail-queue-name}-dlq
```

(just imagine it's not only 1 variable, but a lot of them)

I'd like to extract that into something like:

```
with open('application.yaml', 'r') as file:
        yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(file)


print(yaml['queues']['mail-queue-name']) // print mail-app-test
print(yaml['queues']['mail-dlq-name']) // print mail-app-test-dlq
```

Just a simple example of variable substitution. How can I achieve that? Using other libraries it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may not fulfill your expectations, but the code below gives some insight into implementing your code.

**Sample Code Substitution and Parsing:**

```
import yaml
import re

def subst(match):
    var_name = match.group(1)
    keys = var_name.split('.')
    value = yaml_data
    for key in keys:
        value = value[key]
    return str(value)

with open('example.yaml', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(content)

pattern = re.compile(r'\$\{([^\}]+)\}')  # to find  ${queues.mail-queue-name}
new_content = pattern.sub(subst, content)

parsed_yaml = yaml.safe_load(new_content)
# maybe here, you can save it as another yaml file.

print(parsed_yaml['queues']['mail-queue-name'])  # Output: mail-app-test
print(parsed_yaml['queues']['mail-dlq-name'])    # Output: mail-app-test-dlq
```

**example.yaml:**

```
queues:
    mail-queue-name: mail-app-test
    mail-dlq-name: ${queues.mail-queue-name}-dlq
```

**Output:**

```
mail-app-test
mail-app-test-dlq
```